# Python writing to a new file each new loop

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to use a while loop to write to a series of new files. Each iteration of the loop should write to a new file, and close it before the next loop begins.  I'm using Python 2.7, and I'd like to resolve this without having to install any additional libraries if possible.

I've gotten the program to work for writing to a single file, but once I try to use the loop, the program loops indefinitely, writing over and over to the initial file. It isn't closing the first file and moving to the next loop. Here's the code:

*Update: The problem has been resolved. I moved everything in the while loop to a separate function, and just called it repeatedly in the while loop while incrementing the chapter value of the argument. Also made sure to account for lower case p in the arrow brackets as well as upper case P. Thanks everyone for the help!*

```
import urllib

storyID = raw_input("Please Enter Story ID: ")
chapters = raw_input("Please Enter the number of Chapters: ")
countDown = int(chapters)
countUp = 1

while countUp <= countDown :

    storyURL = "https:website/" + storyID + "/" + str(countUp) + "/"
    f = urllib.urlopen(storyURL)

    with open ('chapter' + str(countUp) + '.html', 'a') as g:

        bof = False
        eof = False


        while eof == False :
            line = f.readline()
            if "<P>" in line and bof == False :
                bof = True
                g.write("""<html>\n<meta charset='utf-8'>\n
                <META NAME='ROBOTS' CONTENT='NOARCHIVE'>\n
                <META http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>\n
                <META NAME='format-detection' content='telephone=no'>\n
                <META NAME='viewport' content='width=device-width'>\n
                <meta name="google-translate-customization" content="6babbc5ad0624c76-e1cef323edf23c09-g0466c4b8ae39c7a2-12">\n""")
                g.write(line)

            elif "Chapter Navigation" in line and bof == True:
                eof = True
                g.write ("</html>")

            elif bof == True :
                g.write(line)
    g.close()
    countUp = countUp + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TRY THIS WAY....when you fetch the url use read() method first
################
import urllib

storyID = raw_input("Please Enter Story ID: ")
chapters = raw_input("Please Enter the number of Chapters: ")
countDown = int(chapters)
countUp = 1

while countUp <= countDown :

    storyURL = "https:website/" + storyID + "/" + str(countUp) + "/"
    f = urllib.urlopen(storyURL)
    data = f.read()

    with open ('chapter' + str(countUp) + '.html', 'w') as g:
          g.write(data)

    countUP = countUp + 1
```

Comment: I tried to run this but got the following error                                    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fetch2.py", line 14, in <module>
    g.write(f)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: miss one step: after open the url use read() method and save the data. Use the saved data and write a file.

Answer (score 0):

Case matters.

```
countUp = countUp + 1
```

Better yet:

```
countUp += 1
```

Comment: So that resolved the issue of it never moving past the first iteration of the outermost while loop. Stupid mistake on my part. But now I'm running into issues with the second loop. It creates the second file but doesn't write anything to it, and seems to loop infinitely as I have to force it to end. Is there something wrong with the way I'm opening , writing and closing the files?